# Password Changes with Ansible (User Accounts)

Tags: password, automation

I am having trouble changing passwords with Ansible. It might be my playbook.

I need to change this password for specific users. The ssh-keys are the same in the authorized keys section. Not sure why this is not connecting to the other machine.

```
- hosts:  HOSTNAME.austin.ibm.com
  tasks:
  - name: Change Root Password
    user: name=root update_password=always password=passw0rd1
```

Here is my error message:

```
ubuntu@ans-test:/etc/ansible$ sudo ansible-playbook -s password.yml 
sudo: unable to resolve host ans-test

PLAY [HOSTNAME.austin.ibm.com] **************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
The authenticity of host 'HOSTNAME.austin.ibm.com (9.3.214.197)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:pX3FVgOCBmVTy29IbM+uPQkKYDa3GBehj4t1BekZxGw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
fatal: [arlz197.austin.ibm.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @password.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
HOSTNAME.austin.ibm.com     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Comment: Its a connectivity issue. Can you do `ssh arlz197.austin.ibm.com` directly? If not, run `ssh` with `ssh -vvv arlz197.austin.ibm.com`

Comment: It's not a connection issue because a key is getting checked.  Is your /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file chmodded to 600?